# weird grid results when 'Puppies' button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, grid

I have a fake dog adoption site and I am just a beginner, so it is nothing special.  I have it set up so that you can click on 1 of 6 buttons and it will display a small picture of each dog that fits the description.  If you click the button a 2nd time, the pictures disappear.

It seems that everything is functional EXCEPT the 'Puppies' button has a weird affect on the 'Special Needs' button.  I don't know why, but the one button changes the position of the other.  I have been working on this all weekend and I am so close to getting it to look right.

Please, if you can figure out what I am doing wrong, please let me know!

```js
//---------------------------------------------------------//
var MaleArray = [
  "<a href='Boris.html'><img src='BorisGut.jpg' alt='marker.gif' style='width:20%'></a>",
  "<a href='Harley.html'><img src='Harley Santa hat.jpg' alt='image.gif' style='width:20%'></a>",
  "<a href='Max.html'> <img src='Max.png' alt='image.gif' style='width:20%'></a>",
];

function showMalesFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("MalesBtn");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block"
    document.getElementById("MalesBtn").innerHTML = MaleArray;
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------//
var FemaleArray = [
  "<a href='Lucy.html'><img src='LucyPage.jpg' alt='image.gif' style='width:20%'></a>",
  "<a href='Daisy.html'><img src='DaisyBirthdayHat.jpeg' alt='image.gif' style='width:20%'></a>",
  "<a href='Honey.html'><img src='Honey.png' alt='image.gif' style='width:20%'></a>",
  "<a href='Dolly.html'><img src='Dolly.jpg' alt='image.gif' style='width:20%'></a>",
  "<a href='Birdie.html'> <img src= 'Birdie Girdie.jpg' alt='image.gif' style='width:20%'></a>"
];

function showFemalesFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("FemalesBtn");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block"
    document.getElementById("FemalesBtn").innerHTML = FemaleArray;
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------//
var PuppiesArray = [
  "<a href='Lucy.html'><img src='LucyPage.jpg' alt='image.gif' style='width:20%'></a>",
  "<a href='Honey.html'><img src='Honey.png' alt='image.gif' style='width:20%'></a>",
  "<a href='Dolly.html'><img src='Dolly.jpg' alt='image.gif' style='width:20%'></a>"
];

function showPuppiesFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("PuppiesBtn");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block"
    document.getElementById("PuppiesBtn").innerHTML = PuppiesArray;
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------//
var AdultArray = [
  "<a href='Boris.html'><img src='BorisGut.jpg' alt='marker.gif' style='width:20%'></a>",
  "<a href='Daisy.html'><img src='DaisyBirthdayHat.jpeg' alt='image.gif' style='width:20%'></a>",
  "<a href='Harley.html'><img src='Harley Santa hat.jpg' alt='image.gif' style='width:20%'></a>",
  "<a href='Birdie.html'> <img src= 'Birdie Girdie.jpg' alt='image.gif' style='width:20%'></a>"
];

function showAdultFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("AdultBtn");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block"
    document.getElementById("AdultBtn").innerHTML = AdultArray;
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------//
var SeniorArray = [
  "<a href='Max.html'> <img src='Max.png' alt='image.gif' style='width:20%'></a>"
];

function showSeniorFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("SeniorBtn");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block"
    document.getElementById("SeniorBtn").innerHTML = SeniorArray;
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------//
var SpecialNeedsArray = [
  "<a href='Dolly.html'><img src='Dolly.jpg' alt='image.gif' style='width:20%'></a>",
  "<a href='Max.html'> <img src='Max.png' alt='image.gif' style='width:20%'></a>"
]

function SpecialNeedsFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("SpecialNeedsBtn");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block"
    document.getElementById("SpecialNeedsBtn").innerHTML = SpecialNeedsArray;
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  border: 2px solid #3399CC;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

td {
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 2px solid #923cb1;
  text-align: left;
}

th {
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 2px solid #3399CC;
  text-align: center;
}

tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #f5fafc;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.grid-container6 {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-column: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  border: 10px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-color: purple;
  border-style: solid;
  column-gap: 10px;
  row-gap: 10px;
  column-rule-color: #e0299a;
  background-color: green;
}

button {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline;
  outline: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  background-color: #002171;
}
```

```html
<main> <br>

  <div class="grid-container6">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- **************   GRID OPEN ************  -->
      <div class="column">
        <button onclick="showMalesFunction()"> Show Male Dogs </button>
        <div id="MalesBtn"> </div>
      </div>
      <!--  ************************************* -->
      <div class="column">
        <button onclick="showFemalesFunction()"> Show Female Dogs </button>
        <div id="FemalesBtn"> </div>
      </div>
      <!--  ************************************* -->
      <div class="column">
        <button onclick="showPuppiesFunction()"> 
        Show Puppy Dogs </button>
        <div id="PuppiesBtn"> </div>
      </div>
      <!--  ************************************* -->
      <div class="column">
        <button onclick="showAdultFunction()"> Show Adult Dogs </button>
        <div id="AdultBtn"> </div>
      </div>
      <!--  ************************************* -->
      <div class="column">
        <button onclick="showSeniorFunction()"> 
          Show Senior Dogs </button>
        <div id="SeniorBtn"> </div>
      </div>
      <!--  ************************************* -->
      <div class="column">
        <button onclick="SpecialNeedsFunction()"> Dogs With Special Needs </button>
        <div id="SpecialNeedsBtn"> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- ************** grid closed ********************-->


  </div>
  </div>
  <!--  ************************************* -->

  <!--  ************************************* -->
  <!--  ************************************* -->
</main>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is while defining, you have not set the display property to each of your display div(s). For instance:

```
<div id="MalesBtn"> </div>
```

So when you try to look for the element,

```
var x = document.getElementById("MalesBtn");
```

then initially x.style.display is ''.

So it goes to the else block and sets its display property to 'none'.

Now when you re-click on the button, this time the if condition `x.style.display === "none"` is satisfied and the element is displayed.

Easier fix would be to check for the display condition first:

```
if (x.style.display === "block") {
  x.style.display = "none";
} else {
   x.style.display = "block"
   x.innerHTML = MaleArray;
}
```